# how i can use talend data intregration metadata in microstrategy?

Tags: etl, talend, business-intelligence, microstrategy

i want data intregration part do with the help of Talend and other reporting, dashboard work will do in microstrategy. How can i connect them ? 
is any odbc or any kind of process is possible ?

Comment: Please specify it's too broad

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to integrate an ETL tool (Talend) to adecuate data for presentation, the only thing that does not sound to clear for me it's why you have interest in integrate them.

They are two process apart, so you can take the processed data thru the ETL tool (Talend or whatever other tool) to a db and that be the source of the BI tool you prefer.

Regards,
Alejandro